# Limiting functionality usage per month in Swift

Tags: swift, date, in-app-purchase

There are a lot of apps that allow the user to use a functionality a certain number of times per month. And when the quota is reached that functionality is blocked till the end of the month.

I am trying to do the same thing and I seem to have run into a bit of a problem.

```
struct Data{
    var text:String
    var date:Date
}

var array : [Data] = [
        Data(text: "Cars", date: Date()),
        Data(text: "Bikes", date: Date()),
        Data(text: "Trucks", date: Date())
    ]

func countForCurrentMonth(date: Date) -> Int{
    let currentMonth = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
    print(currentMonth)
    var datesArray = [Int]()
    for item in array{
        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: item.date)
        if month == currentMonth{
            datesArray.append(month)
        }
    }
    let itemCount = datesArray.count
    return itemCount
}


func addItem(){
    
    if countForCurrentMonth(date:Date()) > 120{
      //functionality locked
        print("subscribe to unlock")
   }else{
       //allowed
        print("allowed")
   }
}
```

The problem is here, the date property is compared with `Date()` which gives the users system date. As the users system date can be manually set, one could easily by bypass this limitation.

So my question is, how can I implement the same thing without using the system date and which doesn't require an internet connection.

One of the things that I tried was keeping a stored date on the device and every time the user opens the app it checks the system date and if it's not equal to the stored date incrementing the day count and replacing the stored date with the new date. However, this would only work if the user opens the app everyday of the month.

Comment: How critical is it to make this absolutely accurate? If not too critical, a simple workaround is to store a 'lastSeen' date, and if the current date is before that assume someone is trying to beat the system and fail.  It'd probably be easier to use a dictionary to store the data in, with a month key and a count value.  Or maybe a year/month key, so it copes with multiple years.

Comment: As the app uses IAP I feel that is unfair to the paid users that some users could trick the system and get free access. What you suggested is heading in the right direction but it still isn't sufficient in this case.

Comment: My view would be that unless there is a huge value IAP to try to scam you are spending a lot of time, effort, and code complexity (and hence bug potential, especially when you start to think about time zones) to address such a small % of dodgy users that it's not cost-efficient.  Most people won't run a device with the wrong date just to save a few pennies,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a proper solution for this without an internet connection but you cloud also save the latest registered date your app has been used with. This way you could check if the current date is earlier and lock your app for instance and try to fetch the correct timestamp online, if possible.

But it may be possible this leads to other issues when the user travels and changes his timezone for example but generally this solution should work.

Comment: This idea crossed my mind too. Just trying see if there's a better way, as I know a  apps that do this without a network connection.

Comment: I mean you wouldn't have to use a internet connection – Just assume that the user is cheating if you Cann't verify is an option. I'm just not quite sure if this is a nice solution but it would work out for you.

Comment: Besides that you do just compare the months, don't you? In this case the most "critical" moment for being false (in case of the timezone thing e.g.) is when a new month just started. Anytime else it's pretty solid.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to store the date and have it be a crucial component. That way if a user was cheating, when compared to other users the date would be too far in the future to count in the app against the competition. Then you would just store the latest date and any earlier date would invalid the session or lock the progress of the app. For instance you could say apply changes to the user account if current date < item date. This could be a problem if you update all users every few seconds. But, in that case you'd probably be online. In this case it seems you want to limit by month though. So even if the user applied 120 changes this month and another 120 changes next month, the changes would only be valid in that next month. So they still get the number of changes applied in that month. Or the first 120 of them. Also, you may want to check the year while you're looking for valid dates.